# Как правильно: "поешь" или "покушай"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Часто слышу, как мамы зовут своих детей "покушать".Правильно ли так говорить?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Мы, как правило, едим, а не кушаем.

Есть  – это дословно «принимать еду»,  общеславянское слово индоевропейского  характера, сравнить edo  (лат) – ем.

Кушать  (от «кусити») –  это изначально «пробовать», общеславянское слово, которое только в восточнославянском варианте  получило значение  «есть» .

До революции слово «кушать»  имело слащавый, подобострастный оттенок, например: "Старшему лакею Никите было поручено обучать Петьку лакейской должности. В другой раз Петька скажет про господ: "Поели". И снова начинается муштровка: "Покушали, покушали. Господа не едят, а кушают". Если выразиться дословно, господа не ели, а только изысканно  "пробовали" еду.

В XIX и начале XX века "кушать, покушать, выкушать" можно было не только еду, но и питье. Вот как это произносили слуги по отношению к господам: "Пожалуйте чай кушать", "извольте откушать ухи", "кушать подано".

В наше время глагол "кушать" – это приглашение к еде. Как-то неловко сказать: «Ешьте, гости», они же не есть пришли, а приятно провести время, попробовать ваше угощение. И по отношению к детям  ласковое «кушать» вполне допустимо: «Кушай поскорее, и пойдем гулять!»

Во всех остальных случаях оттенок ласковой слащавости желательно исключить.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно и так, и так - все зависит от ситуации. Когда Вы обращаетесь к человеку, особенно близкому, то уместнее будет сказать "покушай". Это вежливое приглашение человека к еде. Если же Вы говорите о себе, то тут есть нюансы. В устах мужчин "кушать" звучит излишне сюсюкающе и вообще некрасиво. А вот ребенок или женщина может.

Comment: Я почему спросила. У меня бабушка говорила "покушай" в смысле "попробуй", , пересолено или недосолено, а если есть, то есть, в смысле еды. Не знаю, правильно это или нет.

Comment: >У меня бабушка говорила "покушай" в смысле "попробуй",   
  
Для бабушки - правильно. )))  
Это исходное значение слова покушай. В литературном языке сейчас не сохранилось, но в языке народном, в диалектах - вполне могло.  
  
Вообще исходите из того, что бабушки никогда не говорят неправильно. если, конечно, не считать неправильностями диалектные и фонетические особенности.